# How to loop in Ansible $var number of times?

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible, nested-loops

I want to run a loop in Ansible the number of times which is defined *in* a variable. Is this possible somehow?

Imagine a list of servers and we want to create some numbered files on each server. These values are defined in vars.yml:

```
server_list:
  server1:
    name: server1
    os: Linux
    num_files: 3
  server2:
    name: server2
    os: Linux
    num_files: 2
```

The output I desire is that the files `/tmp/1`, `/tmp/2` and `/tmp/3` are created on server1, `/tmp/1` and `/tmp/2` are created on server2. I have tried to write a playbook using `with_nested`, `with_dict` and `with_subelements` but I can't seem to find any way to to this:

```
- hosts: "{{ target }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Load vars
      include_vars: vars.yml

    - name: Create files
      command: touch /tmp/{{ loop_index? }}
      with_dict: {{ server_list[target] }}
      loop_control:
        loop_var: {{ item.value.num_files }}
```

If I needed to create 50 files on each server I can see how I could do this if I were to have a list variable for each server with 50 items in it list which is simply the numbers 1 to 50, but that would be a self defeating use of Ansible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a chapter in the docs: [Looping over Integer Sequences](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-integer-sequences) (ver 2.4)

For your task:

```
- file:
    state: touch
    path: /tmp/{{ item }}
  with_sequence: start=1 end={{ server_list[target].num_files }}
```

**Update:** things has changed in Ansible 2.5. See separate docs page for [sequence](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/sequence.html) plugin.

New `loop` syntax is:

```
- file:
    state: touch
    path: /tmp/{{ item }}
  loop: "{{ query('sequence', 'start=1 end='+(server_list[target].num_files)|string) }}"
```

Unfortunately `sequence` accepts only string-formatted parameters, so parameters passing to `query` looks quite clumsy.

Comment: The link has no chapter 'Looping over Integer Sequences', actually im now looking for how to create a simple for loop ...

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python:

```
- file:
    state: touch
    path: /tmp/{{ item }}
  loop: "{{ range(1, (server_list[target].num_files | int + 1)) }}"
```